# Totalizar operaciones de los campos de una tabla datatable en un campo

Tags: jquery, datatables

Actualmente me encuentro trabajando con tablas DataTable de jQuery y tengo una tabla que cuenta con un campo de disponibles:

[image: TABLA DATATABLE JQUERY]

Como se aprecia en la imagen, la tabla cuenta con los campos: troncales, isdn, R2, V5.2, disponibles y total, el campo disponibles debería ser el resultado de la siguiente operación:

```
((troncales + isdn + R2 + v5.2) - Total)
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que jQuery me ejecute esa operación y automáticamente el resultado se refleje en el campo disponibles? Actualmente los datos los ingreso de forma manual pero debiera ser automático.

Para la tabla utilizo: jQuery, PHP7, MySQL, AJAX y JSON.

---

Así se ve ahora el campo:

[image: Tabla con el proceso corriendo pero arroja NAN]

Me dice que no es un número. Imagino que se debe transformar el string en un INT pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

---

Así estoy agregando la función en el JavaScript:

[image: Agregando la funcion a Jquery]

Comment: Hola, el código es mejor que lo compartas en modo texto en lugar de como imágenes. Es más accesible y más fácil de leer para todos los usuarios. Lee [ask] y [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, verificable y completo?](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el método `render` https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render en `columnDefs` https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs

```
"columnDefs": [
{
    "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return ( Number(row.troncales) + Number(row.isdn) + Number(row.r2) + Number(row.v52) - Number(row.total) );
    },
    "targets": 4
}
```

Tendrías que reemplazar los nombres de celda que pongo de ejemplo por los reales que hayas utilizado y el `targets` por el índice de la columna en la que se debería mostrar el total.

Comment: Gracias amigo al parecer si funciona, solo que el resultado me refleja que no es un numero? como hago para transformar los datos que son tomados como string en enteros?  Muchas gracias por la ayuda...

Comment: Habría que ver tu código para saber si está mal que convierta cada uno o si deberías modificar el tipo de valor de alguna o todas las columnas. Agregalo a la pregunta y lo vemos.

Comment: Me refiero al `PHP` que trae datos y al bloque  `jQuery` que define las columnas del `datatable`, porque puede haber errores en cómo trae datos desde la BD ... por ej., que R2 no traiga `100` sino `  100  ` (con espacios).
Prueba haciéndolo en forma gradual:
En lugar de mi código, probar `"columnDefs": [ "render": function ( data, type, row ) { return row.troncales + 1 ); }, "targets": 4 }`
Si funciona, probar con otro: `"columnDefs": [ "render": function ( data, type, row ) { return row.isdn + 1 ); }, "targets": 4 }`

Hasta que encuentres qué columna/s está/n mal.